# Overlay Menu button on my open layers 3 map

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to overlay a menu button on my map. So when I click this button it will apper a window. I created the map div and the overlayMenu button div but it doesn't show me the button where I want. I want the pointed button to be near to the zoom buttons and the white area to disapear.

[image]

Here is the code to the HTML file:

```
<div id="map" style="width:100%; height:100%; z-index: 0">
<div id="overlayMenu" style="z-index:9999"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control the placement of the menu button over the map using the [CSS Position Property](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp).

You may also need to give the menu a positive `z-index`. Note that the [z-index Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) only applies to "positioned" elements - elements with position other than `static`.

```
#overlayMenu {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 10px;
    left: 50px;
}
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. I just had to change a little bit the top and left parameters but the code lines are exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

you can always give it position absolute, but be carefull, if the map can be smaller(not filling the window) the button will stay there, floating in the middle of nowhere.

Comment: In fact the map it's bigger than the display, removing the button from the current position i think will make the map fit perfectly.